# Are any C# constructs toplevel-only?

Tags: c#

Some C# constructs cannot be used at top level. For example, methods cannot be defined at top level; they must be within a class.

Are there any language constructs that can *only* be used at top level, that *cannot* be nested within other constructs?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - all of those can be nested within namespaces themselves, at the least.

Comment: Can you explain why you are asking? Is there a subtext to this question?

Comment: @mjwills The context is a compiler I am writing for which C# is a target language, but it's a general question about C# syntax regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global attributes are the only thing I can think of, and searching the formal grammar [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces) seems to confirm that.

> The *global_attributes* ([Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes)) of a compilation unit permit the specification of attributes for the target assembly and module.

Everything else that can be in a `compilation_unit` can also be contained within a `namespace_body`:

```
compilation_unit
    : extern_alias_directive* using_directive* global_attributes? namespace_member_declaration*
    ;

namespace_declaration
    : 'namespace' qualified_identifier namespace_body ';'?
    ;

namespace_body
    : '{' extern_alias_directive* using_directive* namespace_member_declaration* '}'
    ;

namespace_member_declaration
    : namespace_declaration
    | type_declaration
    ;
```

(Other parts of the grammar from the page and all narrative removed)